# Siri Api Custom Command's

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri

I want to know if it's possible to add custom command's with Siri, Like:

I want to add command:

Please turn on flash light, it will turn on flash light

Please turn off flash light, it will turn off flash light.

Please help me is this possible?

If yes please guide me with a link or tutorial.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The voice recognition is done by Apple's servers.  There's no (known) API for doing per-app recognition.

Comment: @Avi I want to create an application in which i can do turn on flash light and turn off flash light is it possible to add some custom defined command's to siri on installation of application?

Comment: How would that work?  There's no API to pass audio to Siri.  Apple wouldn't know what to return to you anyway, and if you want speech-to-text, you can  find libraries that do that for you, but natural speech parsing is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one clever work around. Although Siri has no API, you can use Siri to send texts. If you send texts to IFTTT, then you can have IFTTT to trigger events in your app.